# Reset individual cxRadioGroup1's Item ItemIndex to -1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

The line :

> cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex :=-1;

resets all itemindexes of all items to -1 in the radiogroup.
How do you handle individual items in the mentioned group i.e 
reset `ItemIndex` of an individual item to -1 ?

Comment: what do you mean by "reset itemindex of an individual item to -1"? there is no itemindex property for all items.

Comment: @sddk if you have 5 items in the radiogroup (1,2,3,4,5)  I would like to reset only the itemindex of 3.

Comment: Do you mean set it (item 3) as unchecked?

Comment: I dont think they have an itemindex, only the RadioGroup has an itemindex. It is still not clear to me what you want, please explain more

Comment: @sddk yes ... just like unchecked ...

Comment: setting ItemIndex property of cxRadioGroup to -1 will do that, as you've written into the question. Do not forget only one item can be checked in a RadioGroup.

Comment: you can probably reach individual items like this `radioGroup1.Properties.Items[2]` but it sitl does not have any itemindex. Setting the itemindex of the radiogroup itself will achieve what you want i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using `TcxRadioGroup`, use `TcxCheckGroup` instead.

In `TcxRadioGroup` any item has an index.

- Setting `TcxRadioGroup.ItemIndex` property you will activate the corresponding item and deactivate all the others.
- Setting `-1` as `ItemIndex` causes all items to be deactivated. (It's like a combobox, only one item can be selected at a time).

If you want to control the state of each item individually, you should use `TcxCheckGroup` instead.
[Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q530504/how-to-set-checked-state-in-tcxcheckgroup) you can find an example explaining how to set the state of a `TcxCheckGroup`'s item:

```
<AcxCheckGroup>.States[<AIndex>] := cbsChecked;
```

Answer (score 0):

for Setting a RadioGroup if you put the value -1 in the ItemIndex will end up not selecting any item from the component.
In the RadioGroup it is not possible to select more than one item, so much the ItemIndex belongs to the radioGroup.